# Using different versions of .net DLL in one application in different OS

Tags: c#, .net

How can i configure a .net application to use different versions of a dll in different OS

Let me elaborate in details.

I have a .net application that needs a dll under version .net 2.0 in Windows7 and lower OS but it require the same dll under version 4.0 in Windows8 OS.If i use the .net 2.0 versioned dll in Windows 8 then the application will crash.So i created the same dll under .net 4.0.But i don't know how can i tell my application to use  the different versioned dll in different OS.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Using .NET assembly binding redirection, check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.71).aspx